# Handle skype message using Ruby

Tags: ruby, skype

Is there any library that allows to handle Skype messages using Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://rubyforge.org/projects/skyperapper

If you are using JRuby http://skype.sourceforge.jp/ might be a better option

For the public API doc: http://developer.skype.com/accessories

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RestClient gem and the tropo.com service to send and receive Skype IMs. See the documentation for their REST api here:

https://www.tropo.com/docs/scripting/message.htm?search=skype#anchor

They're currently not charging for the service that sends/receives instant messages.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two ways of accessing the Skype network in a sanctioned manner. The first is the Skype Public API, which requires talking to the official Skype client running on a local machine. The other is SkypeKit which I am led to believe has a very restrictive agreement attached to it.

[SkypeKit for ruby is available as a gem here.](https://github.com/railsware/skypekit)

The following is historical only; Skype no longer supports the Public API for their client. <del>I have also been working on [a Ruby wrapper around the Skype Public API](https://github.com/mscharley/ruby-skype). It's far from finished at the moment but supports Windows and Linux currently (OSX should be easy to implement as well, however I currently don't have a Mac) and allows you to connect and send commands to Skype manually. Long term the entire API will be wrapped.</del>

In the interests of full disclosure, there seem to be a few other projects hanging around too, however they seem to only target a single platform and the ones I found seem to be abandonware at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

libpurple have a plugin for Skype, but this is not easy to Setup.

Unfortunately, Skype protocol is closed & encripted, so there are no good libs out there.